# Evaluate the limit of $(\sqrt{(1-x)}-3)/(2+\sqrt[3]x)$ as $x\rightarrow-8$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit  $$\lim _{x\rightarrow-8}\frac {\sqrt{(1-x)}-3}{2+\sqrt[3]x}$$

I'm trying to solve this problem but strangely I'm getting different results. I think I have problems while factoring the roots,I used the basic formula $$a^3-b^3=(a+b)(a^2 - ab + b^2)$$ to factor out the bottom and the $(a^2-b^2)$ formula to factor the top, at the end I'm getting the result $-1$, while in online equation solver the result is $0$. I just wanna be sure if I'm doing it correct. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Write

$$\sqrt{1-x}-3=\frac{-(x+8)}{\sqrt{1-x}+3}$$

And

$$2+x^{1/3}=\frac{x+8}{x^{2/3}-2x^{1/3}+4}$$

The limit of interest is $-2$.

Answer (score 1):

The basic formula that you are using is wrong, the formula actually is

$$ a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2). $$

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\lim _{x\rightarrow-8}\frac {\sqrt{(1-x)}-3}{2+\sqrt[3]x}$$

let $y=\sqrt[3]x$ then

$$L=\lim _{y\rightarrow-2}\frac {\sqrt{(1-y^3)}-3}{2+y} \tag 1$$

which is in the form of a derivative
$$L = f'(-2) \text{ where } f(x) =  \sqrt{1-y^3}$$

If you are not allowed to use derivatives just multiply numerator and denominator by  $\sqrt{(1-y^3)}+3$

p.s. the answer should be $L=-2$

Answer (score 1):

Using the formulas above correct and with the help you provided me I was able to reach the result which in this case is: -2, which it seems to be correct, thanks for all you help.

Comment: You're welcome!  It was my pleasure.  -Mark  ... and I up voted both this answer and your question.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward application of L' Hopital's rule gives

$\lim _{x\rightarrow-8}\frac {\sqrt{(1-x)}-3}{2+\sqrt[3]x} = \lim _{x\rightarrow-8}\frac{-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{1-x}}}{\frac{1}{3 x^{2/3}}} = \lim _{x\rightarrow-8}-\frac{3 x^{2/3}}{2\sqrt{1-x}} = -2$